Why Gram-Schmidt Process fails with vector taken from Column Space of 2 Vectors.
We are familiar with Gram-Schmidt process. I just want to  know why Gram-Schmidt gives 2 different answers, with and without normalizing.
Let's take 3 vectors a = [ 1;1;2], b= [1;3;1] & c= [1;2;2].
Gram-Schmidt without normalization gives me orthogonal vectors.
A = a = [1;2;2]
B = b - (A^T.b)*A/(A^T.A) = [ 0;2;-1]
C = c - (A^T.c)*A/(A^T.A) - (B^T.c)*B/(B^T.B) = [-0.1667; 0.033; 0.0667]
everything is orthogonal even without normalizing A,B and C using norm() in MATLAB
Simplifying Gram-Schmidt by taking a vector X from the plane of A & B.
This vector X if X = suppose c1 * A + c2 * B; c1 and c2 are constants
If I find C' by projection onto X only i.e. I mean in a single step it must be orthogonal to A & B since it's orthogonal to a vector in the plane of A & B, it should give me same result.
C = c - (X^T.c)*A]X/(X^T.X) = [0.4203;
-0.3188;
1.7101]
But NO
Result without normalization suggests C and C' are different without normalization and turn out to be the same after normalization
With Normalization
Without Normalization
magenta is C' and yellow is C.
Is this some MATLAB specific issue?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
